# Second level sorting using smart table?

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have a paginated table using a smart table. I want to sort using first the status and then the code. I can't use orderBy from AngularJS because it will order the elements of each page, not all. And st-sort-default of smart table orders only for one column.

```
<table st-table="lista.displayedPublications" st-safe-src="lista.publications">
      <thead>
          <tr>
               <th st-sort="publication.status" >STATO</th>
               <th st-sort="publication.communicationCode">TREAT CD</th>                      
               <th> ... </th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="publication in lista.displayedPublications">
               <td>{{publication.status}}</td>
               <td>{{publication.communicationCode}}</td>
               <td>...</td>                 
           </tr>
       </tbody>
             <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div st-template="ListaTreatement/pagination.html" st-pagination="" st-items-by-page="10"></div>
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </tfoot>
  </table>
```

In the controller:

```
public publications: PublicationExtended[];
public displayedPublications = [].concat(this.publications);
constructor(...){
     new Api($http).getList(me.comunicationType, me.comunicationStatus).then(
        function(response : angular.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<PublicationExtended[]>) {
            me.publications = response.data;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `$filter("orderBy")($scope.lista.displayedPublications, ["+status", "+code"]);` in your controller to sort your data before providing it to your table. `+` and `-` can be used to set descending or ascending sort order.

Comment: I have this in my controller public displayedPublications = [].concat(this.publications);

Comment: Please provide the angularjs code that deals with this table

Comment: `public displayedPublications = $filter("orderBy")( [].concat(this.publications), ["+status", "+code"]);` instead of `public displayedPublications = [].concat(this.publications);` would probably do the trick. Remember to inject $filter into your controller.

Comment: I resolved using simply me.publications = $filter('orderBy')(response.data, ['+status','+code']);

Comment: Well since you mentioned the OrderBy filter, I used OrderBy to solve your problem. You can use any custom filter you want to sort your data, and the solution will still hold the same principles.